# Where is the best place to define variable?

Tags: performance, variables, scope, location, definition

I am wondering about does it any difference the below code for performance or something? For example there is three variables and each one is when to use is defined.

```
    bool myFunc()
    {
        string networkName;
        if ( !Parse(example, XML_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, networkName) )
        {
            return false;
        }

        BYTE networkId;
        if ( !Parse(example, XML_ATTRIBUTE_ID, networkId) )
        {
            return false;
        }

        string baudRate;
        if ( !Parse(example, XML_ATTRIBUTE_BAUDRATE, baudRate) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Does it any difference between above and below code for performance or something?

```
    bool myFunc()
    {
        string networkName;
        string baudRate;
        BYTE networkId;

        if ( !Parse(example, XML_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, networkName) )
        {
            return false;
        }

        if ( !Parse(example, XML_ATTRIBUTE_ID, networkId) )
        {
            return false;
        }

        if ( !Parse(example, XML_ATTRIBUTE_BAUDRATE, baudRate) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Code Readability

- The **recommended** practice is to put the declaration as close as possible to the first place where the variable is used. This also minimizes the scope. 
  From *Steve McConnell's "Code Complete"* book:

  > *Ideally, declare and define each variable close to where it’s first
  >   used.* A declaration establishes a variable’s type. A definition assigns
  >   the variable a specific value. In languages that support it, such as
  >   C++ and Java, variables should be declared and defined close to where
  >   they are first used. Ideally, each variable should be defined at the
  >   same time it’s declared.
- Nevertheless, **few** sources recommend placing declarations in the beginning of the block (`{}`).
  From the *obsolete* [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141270.html#16817):

  > Put declarations only at the beginning of blocks. (A block is any code
  >   surrounded by curly braces "{" and "}".) Don't wait to declare
  >   variables until their first use; it can confuse the unwary programmer
  >   and hamper code portability within the scope.
- Declaring variables *only* at the top of the function is considered **bad practice**. Place declarations in the most local blocks.

---

### Performance

- In fact, it depends. Declaring POD types should not affect performance at all: the memory for all local variables is allocated when you call the function (`C`, `JavaScript`, `ActionScript`...).
- Remember that the compiler optimizes your code, so I guess non-POD types also wouldn't be a problem (`C++`).
- Usually choosing the place to declare a variable is a premature optimization, so the performance is an unimportant point here because of its insignificant microscopic boost (or overhead). The major argument is still the **code readability**.

---

### Additional Note

- Before `C99` (`C` language) standard, variables had to be declared in the **beginning** of the block.

---

### Summarizing

- Considering the above, the best approach (but still not mandatory) is to declare variable as close as possible to the place of its first usage, keeping the scope clean.
- In general, it's just a matter of a **code readability**.

Comment: Hi @kefir500 , Declaring variables only at the top of the function is considered bad practice. Place declarations in the most local blocks. what do you mean when you said this ?

Comment: does it mean declare variable at the beginning of the scope or right before that variable use ?